# In Android 2.3.x text is not showing in two lines

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my code :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
```

In Android version 2.3.2, text is not showing in two lines, while in higher version device the text is showing in 2 lines. Also when I remove the tag ellipsize then text will be shown in 2 lines. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ellipsize tag.  If you really want it for higher versions, add it programatically when you inflate the layout for android versions above 2.3.

Alternatively, use different layouts for 2.3 and before vs 3.0 and later.  But that's more likely to lead to maintenance bugs.  If this is the only difference I wouldn't go that route.

Comment: But I also want to use the tag ellipsize in low version devices.

Comment: Is this issue is coming in 3.0 android device ?
I don't have any 3.0 device and in android virtual devices (for 2.3.x version) this issue is not coming. From which android version I should give the tag ellipsize ?

Comment: Nobody has 3.0 devices.  The 3.X line didn't sell very well, it's only very early Android tablets.  But UI changes probably took place there, as it was a major branch.